# Is there a way to associate Selenium test with an Azure DevOps test case?

Tags: azure-devops

What I'm aiming for is closing the loop on test coverage.

My goal would be:

1. Define test cases with PM and list them out under a Test Plan in Azure DevOps.
2. Associate Selenium tests in Visual Studio with specific test case(s).
3. When the release pipeline runs the UI test, I would expect to see on the dashboard the % of test cases that passed/failed or were not even associated.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops

> Coded UI test, Selenium tests, and unit tests written using Version 1
>   of the MSTest framework can be associated with a test case.

The process to associate an automated test with a test case is:

1. Create a test project containing your automated test.
2. Check your test project into an Azure DevOps repository.
3. Create a build pipeline for your project, ensuring that it contains the automated test.
4. Use Visual Studio Enterprise or Professional 2017 or a later version to associate the automated test with a test case. The test case must have been added to a test plan that uses the build you just defined.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to associate Selenium tests written in Java to Azure DevOps test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension that **I have created** https://github.com/JanuszNowak/janono.ado.testcase.associate.cli . It allows associating in automatic manner. So if yours selenium test are using xunit, nunit or mstest you can **associate them automatically**.

Code sample:

```
namespace ExampleTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    [janono.ado.testcase.associate.Organization("janono-pub")]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [janono.ado.testcase.associate.TestCase(5)] //<---
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //yours test method content
            //...
            //
        }
    }
}
```